# HIde / Show Controls in nested FormView using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Up on Editing I want to Hide MyTextBox when MYCheckBox is checked using javascript. I am able to find confrols in ParentFormView using

```
var MyTextboxINParentFV= document.getElementById('<%=ParentFormView.FindControl("MyTextboxINParentFV").ClientID %>');
```

But by now I can't get controls in ChildFormView,Can any one help me out please?

```
<asp:formview ID="ParentFormview" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox  ID="MyTextBoxInParentFV" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                 <asp:CheckBox ID="MYCheckBoxInParentFV" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>    
       <asp:FormView ID ="ChildFormView1" runat="server">
           <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox  ID="MyTextBoxInChildFV" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                 <asp:CheckBox ID="MYCheckBoxInChildFV" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:FormView>
   </ItemTemplate>
     <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox  ID="MyTextBoxInParentFv" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                 <asp:CheckBox ID="MYCheckBoxInParentFV" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox> 
         <asp:FormView ID="ChildFormView2" runat="server">
             <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox  ID="MyTextBoxInChildFV" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                 <asp:CheckBox ID="MYCheckBoxInChildFV" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
             </EditItemTemplate>            
         </asp:FormView>
    </EditItemTemplate>   
</asp:formview>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a class name to the controls of the inner FormView:

```
<asp:FormView ID ="ChildFormView1" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox  ID="MyTextBoxInChildFV" runat="server" CssClass="childTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:CheckBox ID="MYCheckBoxInChildFV" runat="server" CssClass="childCheckBox"></asp:CheckBox>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

And retrieve them with that class name:

```
var childFV = document.getElementById('<%=ParentFormView.FindControl("ChildFormView1").ClientID  %>');
var childTextBoxes = childFV.getElementsByClassName('childTextBox');
var childCheckBoxes = childFV.getElementsByClassName('childCheckBox');
```

Comment: Thank you sir for replying! when I try to access ChildFormView2 using your logic I am getting null reference exception during pageLoad,is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Only the item in edit mode should give you valid reference to ChildFormView2. If no item is in edit mode, then you will not find that element.

Comment: By the way, does your parent FormView contain a single item? I'm a little surprised that you can access its children by their ID like that. If it has more than one item, you certainly have to specify which item these children belong to.

Comment: To Make it Clear, In Aspx page I have a A ParentFormView which is inside Update Panel. This parentFormView contains lot of Textbox,checkbox and dropdownlist.Beside this it contains a subsection which is a ChildFormView enclosed with its own update Panel. This childFormview also contain  its own Textbox,checkbox and dropdownlist.I have complete access of controls in ParentFormView but not in childFormview.But I have access of Child form view controls from code behind(C#). Thanks

Comment: The items in the Edit,Insert Mode  and display are  same

Comment: According to your markup, the element ChildFormView2 is present only in edit mode.